# What is a Chemical Number™?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

<sub>This is inspired by the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, now with numbers.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Chemical Number™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule:

| A Chemical Number™ | Not a Chemical Number™ |
| --- | --- |
| 81.1801 | 84.2849 |
| 116.64 | 97.3838 |
| 6384.01 | 9372.28 |
| 10609 | 13454 |
| 38025 | 39594 |
| 56644 | 55429 |

Csv version:

```
A Chemical Number™, Not a Chemical Number™
81.1801,84.2849
116.64,97.3838
6384.01,9372.28
10609,13454
38025,39594
56644,55429
```

Why are these called chemical numbers?

Hint 1:

> These are not Chemical Numbers™: 407.2324, 49284, 40236,3481

Answer (score 6):

A Chemical Number™ appears to be one

> whose square root is rational. All of the numbers on the left side have rational square roots: 9.01, 10.8, 79.9, 103, 195, and 238.

Comment: That doesn't address the 'chemical' part. It looks like rot13/ ngbzvp znff is a relevant part of the puzzle.

Comment: @LannyStrack the question post doesn't ask for the reason for the name.

Comment: Sorry, but how is this *chemical*? You are on the right track...

Comment: @msh210 - True, but it is common on this site in an accepted answer to explain how the title ties in to the question. And not only that, but the numbers used are relevant in this regard as well, so not mentioning it wouldn't really make a complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

Finishing up @Deusovi's answer:

A Chemical number is

> A number which is the square of a rational number, and that this rational number is the relative atomic mass of a chemical element, correct to 3 significant numbers.

Proof:

> Beryllium > 9.01
>  Boron > 10.8
>  Bromine > 79.9
>  Rhodium > 103
>  Platinum > 195
>  Uranium > 238

Comment: You're close but not quite, what links these elements together?

Comment: A Chemical Number appears to be as @OmegaKrypton states, but the corresponding rot13(ryrzrag vf fbyvq ng ebbz grzcrengher).

Comment: @JeremyDover thanks for the idea but a lot of elements have solid state under room conditions?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton: Yes, but the numbers given in Hint #1 also meet your criterion, but the OP claims they are NOT chemical numbers. The criterion I suggest above does make the needed differentiation.