# What is a Trinity Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-property

<sub>This is inspired by the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, and the [Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98205/what-is-a-chemical-number?rq=1) series.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Trinity Number™. Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Trinity Number™ | Not Trinity Number™ |
| --- | --- |
| 666 | 777 |
| 1988 | 2020 |
| 2048 | 64 |
| 404 | 200 |
| 4096 | 1024 |
| 1048576 | 2097152 |
| 89 | 97 |
| 20200520 | 20201225 |

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption that each number can be tested for whether it is a Trinity Number™ without relying on the other numbers. These are not the only examples of Trinity Numbers™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these numbers conform to?**

CSV version:

```
Trinity Number™, Not Trinity Number™
666, 777
1988, 2020
2048, 64
404, 200
4096, 1024
1048576, 2097152
89, 97
20200520, 20201225
```

---

Hint:

> If you were to write down all of the numbers on paper, one of the Trinity numbers™ will possibly be not found in the set of Trinity Numbers™ (i.e. depending on how it is written, it could become a non-Trinity Number™).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It appears that each Trinity Number™ encloses at least three separate planar regions inside its digits.  Depending on font/writing conventions, a '4' can contribute zero or one to this total, and a '0' one or two.  If assuming '4'->+1 and '0'->+1, this explains the given lists. '404' would be disqualified if '4's are not enclosed, and slashed '0's would make each NTN containing them ->TN.

Comment: Could you illustrate this with a diagram? I'm not sure I follow... Thanks :)

Comment: @Stiv, he means count the 'holes' of the digits :)

Comment: @Prim3numbah That's infinitely clearer, thanks. 'Planar regions' is not a phrase I've ever come across...